# How to copy a scene in Unity?

Tags: unity, scene

When I use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the current scene to duplicate and then I open the new scene,

I get this error message:

```
The following open scene(s) have been changed on disk:
 Assets/Level3.unity

Do you want to reload the scene(s)?
```

whatever I press leads me to a blank new scene

How can I copy everything from one scene to another?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might not have saved your changes to the current scene before duplicating it. Hit `File -> Save` first, to ensure your latest changes are saved to the scene file on disc before duplicating that file.

As an alternative, you can open the scene you want to clone, then go to `File -> Save As...` and save it under a new name. That will save all the contents of the current scene into a new scene file, giving you a second copy of the scene.

Comment: It is blank my new scene still :(

Comment: Then you'll need to edit your question to walk us through the steps to reproduce this problem in a new, empty project. I've tested both methods described above and they work, so there must be something unusual in your setup. Double check things like free space on disc, file write permissions on the folder, and consider uninstalling and reinstalling Unity if the problem persists.

Comment: Wait it only does not load if I name it level2 anything else is fine???/ I guess ill just live with no level 2 then :(

Comment: Do you have another file somewhere in your project with that name? I'm not able to reproduce this problem even when using the name "level2"

Comment: no but it doesn't really mater anymore does it